# Detect required TypeScript field in runtime

Tags: typescript

I need a way to tell in runtime, whether a specific field is required in a TypeScript interface.

It should look like this:

```js
interface Person {
  name: string
  age?: number
  occupation?: string
}

const person: Person = {
   // values
}

const fields = ['name', 'age', 'occupation']
fields.map(field => {
  // I'm looking for a kind of `isRequired` TypeScript util,
  // that can tell, whether a field in described interface is required
  if (isRequired(person, field)) {
    // do this
  } else {
    // do that
  }
})
```

I think, it should be possible, for example, when at compile time TypeScript creates an  internal array of required fields.

Anybody has implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible for interfaces because they do not exist at runtime. If anything you might be able to do it with a class using [metadata](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata), but I do not know if the optional status is saved in the default metadata.

If this is not the case you may have annotate the properties yourself, at which point you might as well create a mapping/array of required properties manually.